# $PATH error on snow leopard, or RoR install issue?? bad interpreter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, path, osx-snow-leopard

I'm on Snow Leopard and installed ruby, rubygems and rails [the hivelogic way](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/). When I change to my new jekyll project (~/Documents/blog/jekyll), and run

```
[jekyll]$jekyll --server-bash
```

I get:

```
[jekyll]$jekyll --server-bash: /usr/bin/jekyll: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Of interest may be:

```
[jekyll]$which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

And where I presume the problem is:

```
[jekyll]$echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:~/.gem:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/Users/Joe/.gem:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/Users/Joe/.gem:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/bin/gem:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools:/Users/Joe/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/Users/Joe/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools
```

The relevant part of my bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH                            
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Documents/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.6_r1/tools
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting

```
export PATH=/~/.gem:$PATH
```

in my ~/.bash_profile did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Your `$PATH` is a mess. You show `bash_profile` which I presume is `~/.bash_profile` but you don't show `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`. The last two are sourced when you start a non-login interactive shell like you'll get when you use Terminal.app. The "profile" ones are sourced for a login shells. One might source the other if they're set up that way.

If you have `PATH="something:$PATH"` that gets repeatedly executed because you've got one or more of the files listed above sourcing each other, that can lead to the mess you have.

However, the problem with the "bad interpreter" message may not have anything to do with your `$PATH`. That message means that the shebang (in your case `#!/some/path/to/ruby` I think) in a script file is different than where Ruby is actually installed. That's why you'll often see shebangs that look like `#!/usr/bin/env python` so `env` will figure out via `$PATH` where Python (in this case) is located.

Comment: yes I meant ~/.bash_profile. There is nothing of any interest in the other files profile files, but thanks for the info on path and pointing out that the path to ruby was out at some point.